# SameSite in view model on forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have tried sample project form learning forge. it run fine in IIS express. While it run on IIS, it shows SameSite problem. I do want to know where to set the Samesite policies.

**Error Isuue "Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being set in a cross-site context."**

Comment: You are facing this problem in the browsers ?

Comment: Could you try this? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/changes-in-samesite-cookie-in-asp-net-core-and-how-it-impacts/ba-p/1150771